# get current index of post content in category page

Tags: posts, categories

i wanna get the index of current post fetched in a preg_match to be used

```
 if (preg_match('/allowfullscreen/',$content)){



    echo "<script>

    (jQuery)('.showIconIfVideoExists').addClass('working')</script>";}
```

I want to add  a class just for the current post not all posts in each post content that contains the word "allowfullscreen" so i need something like this :

```
('.showIconIfVideoExists').eq(CurrentPostIndex).addClass('working')
```

PS : `$content = get_the_content()`

Comment: If you're on a category page, by definition there is no current post, or rather, every post is the current post at the moment you output it. You'll have to be a lot more specific and descriptive if you mean something else

Comment: yes, that's what i mean .. i just want to add a class for the current post that its content contains "allowfullscreen" ..

Comment: preg_match uses regex for that, it seems overcomplicated, have you considered testing with strpos? Or better yet, just add a checkbox in the backend and store it in post meta